# How can I eliminate gaps in the breadth-first ordering of a binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

A gap-less binary search tree is a self-balancing binary search tree with the *gap-less property*. The *gap-less property* states that there are no gaps in the breadth-first ordering of the tree. A gap in the breadth-first ordering is best defined through a diagram. In the image below, the areas highlighted by red dashed circles are considered gaps in the breadth-first ordering:

[image: tree with gaps]

If this tree were restructured to eliminate the gaps, it would look like this:

[image: tree without gaps]

If the number 7 were added to this restructured tree without re-balancing, it would look like this:

[image: another tree with gaps]

Again, after removing the gaps:

[image: another tree without gaps]

Is there a log(n) algorithm to ensure the *gap-less property* after insertions and deletions to trees of arbitrary sizes?

Comment: something is wrong with restructure in the second image. `2` is a right child of `4` although it's smaller than `4`

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a log(n) algorithm to ensure the *gap-less property* after insertions and deletions to trees of arbitrary sizes?

No.

To see why, consider this tree (which has the gap-less property):

```
           4
          / \
         2   6
        /|   |\
       1 3   5 7
```

To insert 8, you'd need to end up with this:

```
           5
          / \
         3   7
        /|   |\
       2 4   6 8
      /
     1
```

which clearly requires visiting every node at least once, because every single node has a different parent afterward than it had before. Therefore, you cannot possibly guarantee better than *O*(*n*) time.

Likewise, to remove 1, you'd need to end up with this:

```
           5
          / \
         3   7
        /|   |
       2 4   6
```

which, same problem.